# Keep recent n files and delete the rest

Tags: powershell

```
$path = "D:\AccountServiceQAT"
$Temp = "D:\\temp1"
$limit = (Get-Date).Adddays(-5)

$Folder = Get-ChildItem  $path  | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 5

$Folder | Copy-Item -Recurse -Destination $Temp

Remove-Item   $path\* -Recurse
Move-Item $Temp\* -Destination $path
Remove-Item $Temp\* -Recurse
```

How to modify the above script to maintain the latest 5 timestamp folders and delete remaining all without using Temp variable?

Comment: by "latest 5 timestamp folders" you mean the 5 folders with the most recent Creation Time?

Comment: yes  Santiago Squarzon

Comment: $Folder = Get-ChildItem  $path  | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 5 | Remove-Item Please do not try this in production environment. Kindly test and use.

Comment: Do i need to remove all other lines? user2670623

Comment: This is not working

Comment: What's with the requirement `without using Temp variable`? Is it a business requirement (and if yes, what for?) Homework requirement? Something else?

Comment: @vonPryz Why is that important? This doesn't look like a homework question to me just an awkwardly (no offense OP) implemented script.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Because "I want to do X without using Y" without good explanation is often based on misunderstanding language features or suggests a XY problem. Maybe they think Y is too expensive. Maybe instructor that said not to use it. Maybe company policy prevents it. Why guess, though?

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you. Second command is multi-line for readability but it can also be run on a single line:

```
$path = "D:\AccountServiceQAT"

Get-ChildItem -Directory $path | Sort-Object CreationTime |
  Select-Object -SkipLast 5 | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

> **Warning:** I would not test this on real data. Use a dummy test folder to test the above with.

Let's break this down:

- `Get-ChildItem -Directory` only lists directories. Technically containers, but you don't need to worry about that unless you are working with another provider. On a FileSystem, "containers" refers to folders.
- `Sort-Object CreationTime` sorts the returned list by the `CreationTime` property passed down from `Get-ChildItem`.

  - By default `Sort-Object` sorts in ascending order. You can change this with the `-Descending` paramteter.
- `Select-Object -SkipLast 5` skips the last 5 objects returned down the pipeline. In other words it throws them away. This should be your 5 most recent folders.

  - If you were to have used `Sort-Object -Descending`, this would need to be `-Skip 5` instead to skip the *first* 5 objects.
- `Remove-Item` accepts pipeline input for the items to remove. This is compatible with the objects returned from `Get-ChildItem`.

  - `-Recurse` tells `Remove-Item` to recursively delete non-empty folders. Without this it will ask you to confirm the removal of any folders that have child objects (files or folders). You don't want this in automation.
  - `-WhatIf` is used to test `Remove-Item` without actually removing files. It will show output like this:

    ```
    What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\Users\username\Desktop".
    What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\Users\username\Downloads".
    What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\Users\username\Favorites".
    What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\Users\username\Links".
    ```
  - When you are comfortable with the fileset that is going to be removed, replace `-WhatIf` with `-Force`. `-Force` will not prompt to delete read only items, which `Remove-Item` will prompt you on by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bender the Greatest. It is working perfect.  I need one  more thing like how to read the path from pipeline instead of giving in the script

Comment: Please ask a new question for that, it's easy enough but not a simple addition to what you've already asked. What you want info on are begin, process, and end blocks